# Mysql Subtract 'N' days to date value and compare to current date. N and Date are two column values

Tags: mysql, sql, date

My table contains remind_me_befor_days column and expiry_date column.

I have to select records with condition `(expiry_date - remind_me_befor_days) = current_date`.

How this possible by query. Anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do date arithemtics:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.expiry_date - interval t.remind_me_befor_days day = current_date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e31ac6631816930f32e30cb6c3730e4)**:

```
-- sample data
select * from mytable;
```

```
id | expiry_date | remind_me_befor_days
-: | :---------- | -------------------:
 1 | 2019-12-25  |                   10
 2 | 2019-12-25  |                    5
```

```
-- query
select t.*, current_date
from mytable t
where t.expiry_date - interval t.remind_me_befor_days day = current_date
```

```
id | expiry_date | remind_me_befor_days | current_date
-: | :---------- | -------------------: | :-----------
 1 | 2019-12-25  |                   10 | 2019-12-15
```

Answer (score 0):

To split this into a few subproblems, we have:

1. Find the current date.
2. Subtract your `remind_me_befor_days` column value from the `expiry_date` column.
3. Use that as a filter for the records you want from the table.

The first can be done using the MySQL `CURDATE()` function. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp). Combining that with the second and third steps, you get something that looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE expiry_date - remind_me_befor_days = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you write the condition as:

```
where expiry_date = curdate() + interval remind_me_before_days day
```

This is index friendly, so it can make use of an index on `expiry_date`.

Comment: @JobRajan . . . I answered because I think this is the best answer.